# Characteristics of a linear programming problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

How to know if a problem can be solved using linear programming ?

I have to write a statement of a problem to be solved with linear programming, what characteristics of the statement assure me that it can be solved with linear programming ?

Comment: That is much too broad of a question for SO.  There are tons of online resources (and great textbooks) that cover introductory LP.  Please start there.

Comment: @AirSquid Can you give a good reference ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not clear what you want to be assured. 
If you get a statement like 
`min(cx)  s.t. l<=x<=u  b<=Ax<=t` 
(or max) you can be sure that the problem can be solved with linear programming. There are some special linear statements that are used to describe some methods, but these statements are convertible between each other and the most generic is fine to be assured. 
If you want to assure about the problem then it is not clear how you came up with the modality "have to".